Error in symfony for vendor constraint throwable implementation
I have a symfony project and recently started getting this error on console commands with no reason. I don't have a custom validator, it's a simple app with 2 entities and a form. I don't understand what to do to fix this.
PHP Fatal error:  Class Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint cannot implement interface Throwable, extend Exception or Error instead in \vendor\symfony\validator\Constraint.php on line 30

[critical] Fatal Error: Class Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint cannot implement interface Throwable, extend Exception or Error instead


Check line 30 of the indicated file. Does the class implement Throwable?

I don't have to check the line, it's in vendor. I didn't modify anything to make the error appear.

On my project I can see that Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint is an abstract class which doesn't implement anything - what about yours?

It's a required Symfony class that validates entities, apparently removing and installing the package again fixed it. No more errors when clearing cache, no more errors on ajax request. IDK what fixed it.
